# C++ Issue with comparing strings inside array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, duplicates, compare

I have an issue with this part of my big code. Basically, I want the method to check if the names(strings) repeat inside the array and then it prints out which name repeats and how many times. Basically, the main logic is the problem. It doesn't print out anything. Something about the comparing logic is wrong. This is the code for now:

```
string Stringici::GetName(unsigned int index){
    if(index>=0&&index<sizeof(osnove.arr[index])/sizeof(osnove.arr[0])){
        return osnove.arr[index];
    }
    else{
        return "INDEX OUT OF RANGE\n";
    }
}

void Stringici::Comparer(){
    
        for(unsigned int i=0;i<sizeof(osnove.arr)/sizeof(osnove.arr[0])-1;i++){
            for(unsigned int j=i+1;j<sizeof(osnove.arr)/sizeof(osnove.arr[0]);j++){
            
        if(GetName(i)==GetName(j)){
            cout<<"Ime: "<<GetName(i)<<" se ponavlja na "<<i<<". i na "<<j<<". pozicijama\n";
        }
    }
    }   
    
}
```

Comment: What is the issue? Was deleting the comments too much effort? Help us help you by creating a [mcve].

Comment: `sizeof(osnove.arr[index])/sizeof(osnove.arr[0])` is always 1. You are dividing the size of one element by the size of the other - but of course both have the same size. Thus, you almost always end up in "out of range" case; except when `index == 0`

Comment: `index>=0` is always true, seeing as `index` is of an unsigned type. This check is redundant, though harmless.

Comment: I have now fixed that. @Igor Tandetnik No idea how I slipped over that. But the issue still remains the same below. And in the cout part where it is supposed to type it out, the i and j values always show as 0 and 0

Comment: What is `osnove.arr`? Show a [mcve]. My guess is, it's a `string*`, and then `sizeof(osnove.arr)` is the size of the pointer, not the size of the array it points to.

Comment: Yes, it is. A struct member called string* arr. Sorry. I am new to this (first year of Introduction to programming at college) but I am trying so hard to develop my skills. How could I check the size of the array it points to then?

Comment: You would need to store the size somewhere, from the time you've allocated the array and assigned it to this pointer. You can't determine the size from the pointer alone. I imagine somewhere in the code not shown, you have something along the lines of `osnove.arr = new std::string[N];` You need to keep track of the value that `N`. had at that time Or, you could use `std::vector<std::string>`, which does that for you.